# How to convert response body from byteArray to string without using OkHttp own's string method and without loosing information?

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

I am having the following situation:

- OkHttp Call
- store in db the result from: response.body.bytes()
- retrieve later the result
- convert to string

Problem is: when converting OkHttp result from byteArray to string, special characters (like 'é', 'ã', 'ú') are replaced by �. If I just use response.body.string() things work fine, but I have no idea what is going on. Even making a request to google.com.br (or from any other region) toggles this problem, and they are using UTF-8 for sure.

I tried `String(byteArray, charset = UTF-8)` and a lot of similar methods. Nothing worked so far.

So I would like to know, how do I convert the okHttp byteArray result to String without loosing the special characters?

Edit: just this simple code already triggers the problem for me:

> val client = OkHttpClient()
>
> val request = Request.Builder()
>     .url("https://www.google.com.br")
>     .build()
>
> val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
>
> val bytes = response.body()!!.bytes()
>
> println(String(bytes))

Comment: Why not convert to string using OkHttp then store in DB? Also show your code.

Comment: Edit: updated question. // There is nothing special, really. Just this println(String(response.body()!!.bytes())) already toggles the problem. I might, if there is no solution, but if I convert using OkHttp mysterious string function, I need to check if it is not a file or anything else, so it doesn't corrupts an image.

Comment: You need to check the Content-Type encoding. From the OKHttp JavaDoc: *the response as a string decoded with the charset of the Content-Type header. If that header is either absent or lacks a charset, this will attempt to decode the response body in accordance to its BOM or UTF-8.*

Comment: I did try this. I even imported OkHttp code to work with my own, but, since Google is UTF-8 and most Android's method related to String are UTF-8, including String(), I removed to make the sample more brief.

Comment: But if OkHttp's `string()` returns the correct string, then you imported the code wrong.